# AngularJS - ngRepeat on objects return in different order compared vanilla for..in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get Angular's ng-repeat to return objects sorted similar to how the brower's for..in loop returns objects?

http://jsfiddle.net/tgrant54/0dsz4tnz/

My current schema is setup something like so

```js
var schema = {
  1: { id: 'ab1', name: 'Test1' },
  13: { id: 'ab13', name: 'Test13' },
  2: { id: 'ab2', name: 'Test2' },
  12: { id: 'ab12', name: 'Test12' },
  3: { id: 'ab3', name: 'Test3' },
  21: { id: 'ab21', name: 'Test21' },
  131: { id: 'ab131', name: 'Test131' }
};
```

As you can see, I am using an integer for the key. If I use this kind of schema to use with ng-repeat the result comes out in a weird order compared to if I just used vanilla js with a for..in loop. (alphabetical sorting was the problem)

Here is similar HTML I am using:

```html
<div ng-controller='main'>
  <div ng-repeat='(key, obj) in schema'>
      {{key}}: {{obj.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Now here is the output I am getting:

```
1: Test1
12: Test12
13: Test13
131: Test131
2: Test2
21: Test21
3: Test3
```

However, if I were to try doing something similar in vanilla js. I get what I want.

For example with something like this:

```js
for (var k in schema) {
  var ele = document.createElement('div');
  ele.innerHTML = k+": "+schema[k].name;
  document.getElementById('output').appendChild(ele);
}
```

I will get the result I want

```
1: Test1
2: Test2
3: Test3
12: Test12
13: Test13
21: Test21
131: Test131
```

I have tried the toArray filter and even though they come out in the right order, I lose the key in the ng-repeat definition and get the index instead.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out while I was writing the question, so I'll share my findings.

According to the [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) documents:

`You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define what order it will return the keys for an object. (To mitigate this in Angular 1.3 the ngRepeat directive used to sort the keys alphabetically.)`

However, the browsers I have tested on, return the keys sorted numerically. Not what I wanted...

Next bit from the same document:

`Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting. We now rely on the order returned by the browser when running for key in myObj.`

**Update to >= 1.4.0-beta.1**

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgrant54/xL1v0x7g/